# Convert List<Model> to a customised json?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, asp.net-core

I am new to ASP.NET Core. I have tried to generate a **json** `String` with a `List` variable.

In `Developers.cs` Model,

```
public int Id { get; set; }  
public string Name { get; set; }
```

I have added some data to the List

```
List<Developers> list = new List<Developers>();
list.Add(new Developers()
                        {
                            Id = 1;
                            Name = "Senura",
                        });
```

And I have converted that `List` into a `String` by parsing to a json

```
var json =list;
    JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json, Formatting.None, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore, Formatting = Formatting.Indented });
```

---

I am getting this output

```
[{"Id":1,"Name":"Senura"}]
```

I need to get an output like this >> `{"result":[{"Id":1,"Name":"Senura"}]}`

How can I get such?? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need a root object that has a List<Developers> property called Result

Comment: @maccettura Thanks. It works 

Answer (score 1):

I have made a separate Model Class named `DevResult.cs`.

And I have added a `Result` property which accepts a `List<Developers>`.

And then created a variable from the newly created Model (`DevResult.cs`). And assigned the `list` variable to the `Result` property.

```
DevResult devRes = new DevResult()
            {
                Result = list,
            };
```

And serialized `DevResult` variable to json object

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(devRes, Formatting.None, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore, Formatting = Formatting.Indented });
```

Now it returns `{"Result":[{"Id":1,"Name":"Senura"}]}`

*Big Thanks goes to @maccettura who has helped in the comments section.*